# Separating functionality between different users

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Long story short - I have a button that generates a file that is being used for that particular click.

At the moment if two people log into the page, when the second one clicks the button, it will screw up the first one's file since the page changes for every single user.

How can I separate the actions, so that no matter how many people click that button, they will have their own file generated?

I read about PHP sessions however the explanations I found are extremely basic, and I'm not sure if that's what I am after. Can you please suggest a solution and point me in a direction onto what to read?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the lame question.

EDIT:

Thank you for confirming this. In that case, can you please check if the following makes sense. This is my current file generation PHP:

```
<?php  
$extension = ".txt";  
$fname = "temp/" . substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7).$extension;  
$file = fopen($fname, 'w');  
?>
```

If I change it to the following, would it create a new file name for each session:

```
<?php
session_start();
$extension = ".txt";  
$_SESSION["filename"] = "temp/" . substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7).$extension;  
$file = fopen($_SESSION["filename"], 'w');  
?>
```

And then I will need to call the filename by the variable $_SESSION["filename"]?

I know this is some really basic stuff however I haven't had to use them previously.

Comment: yes .. sessions .. to broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, php sessions can be used for your problem. Here is what your solution can look like

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

//set your session variables per user
$_SESSION["userName"] = "Jimmy";
$_SESSION["userCity"] = "Miami";

//then call your session data like this wherever you need it
echo "username is " . $_SESSION["userName"];

?>
```

More info. Your random name generator code looks like it can work. An alternative, which is always unique, less work , and can help you look for seeing when a file was created is to name the file with the UNIX time stamp. This is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch.

tl:dr 
I would do something like this

```
$fileName = time();      //outputs something  like 1435540343
$_SESSION["filename"] = "temp/".$fileName.$extension;  //out -> 1435540343.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I edited my initial comment with a bit more context since you confirmed it's sessions I'm looking for.

Comment: Makes sense. I just needed a confirmation that I'm looking in the right direction. Thank you for your time and the suggestion :)